# Remove duplicates from ArrayList of Sets | ArrayList<Set<String>> tmp

Tags: java, arraylist, set

I have an ArrayList of Set of Strings; `ArrayList<Set<String>> tmp`

I need to use this type of data structure because of my requirement. How can I remove duplicates from this?

For example, how to convert;

```
[[A, B, C], [B, A, C], [C, D, E], [E, C, D]]
```

to

```
[[A, B, C], [C, D, E]]
```

I did go through the other similar answers here, but they are concatenating all the items into one list, for the above example `[[A, B, C, D, E, F]]`
I **DONOT** want this

Answer (score 1):

the same way you remove duplicates from any other ArrayList...

For example:

`tmp.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());`

*Note:* this assumes that the list items implement a suitable `equals` method. As they should.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it:

```
    List<Set<String>> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
    tmp.add(new HashSet<>(List.of("A", "B", "C")));
    tmp.add(new HashSet<>(List.of("B", "A", "C")));
    tmp.add(new HashSet<>(List.of("C", "D", "E")));
    tmp.add(new HashSet<>(List.of("E", "C", "D")));

    Iterator<Set<String>> it = tmp.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        Set<String> currentSet = it.next();

        for (Set<String> set : tmp)
        {
            if (currentSet != set
                    && currentSet.containsAll(set)
                    && currentSet.size() == set.size())
            {
                it.remove();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(set);
```

Output:

```
[[A, B, C], [C, D, E]]
```

Answer (score 0):

HashSet is working on hash algorithm,

So if you have two Set of **String** which contains the same value then hashcode of that set will always be same (As String has special allocation in java).

So you can try like below.

```
    List<Set<String>> tmp = new ArrayList<Set<String>>();
    tmp.add(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"A","B","C"})));
    tmp.add(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"B","A","C"})));
    tmp.add(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"C","D","E"})));
    tmp.add(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"E","C","D"})));

    List<Set<String>> list =new ArrayList<>();

    for(Set<String> s: tmp){
        if(!list.contains(s)){
            list.add(s);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(list);
```

Will result like

```
[[A, B, C], [C, D, E]]
```